# How to persist the DropDownList DataSource, populated from Linq query

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu

I am populating a DropDownList from some Linq query, such as

```
var myTypes = from tableAlias in MyContext.MyTable ...;
dddTypes.DataSource = myTypes;
```

I want to be able to save the Linq query result either from myTypes or the DropDownList DataSource, so that it could be used in other methods.  A variable of type `var` can only be local.

What does the data need to be casted to? Thanks.

Comment: @Davide Piras - Datasets work with both web / form controls.

Comment: I know, but I asked something different

Comment: Asp.net, though as JonH said it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<MyTable>` or you could just convert it to a list with `myTypes.ToList()`. The var variable actually is typed by the ling query, so if you add a break point after the query and hover over the myTypes variable, Intellisense will show you the type.

Answer (score 0):

What if `myTypes` was stored as a dataset?
You could then maintain the data via the dataset.
A datasource can be assigned from the value of a dataset.

And now that you also mentioned you're using asp.net that dataset can be stored in a session state if required.

See [this](http://blog.renjucool.com/2010/05/converting-var-to-dataset.html)

Comment: I'm having trouble calling this.  It should be called as DataSet ds = ToDataSet<SomeAnonType>(myTypes) where SomeAnonType is from System.Linq.IQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType6<SomeAnonType>> here (my debug info)?